# Problem with strapi media library - access only for creator not working

Tags: permissions, strapi, media-library

i have this problem with strapi media library.

Situation is, i have lets say 3 users

- user 1 - Super Admin
- user 2 - Author (role - should see only what is created by him)
- user 3 - Author (same as previous)
  this setup should behave like when user 2 uploads some image into media library, user 3 should not be able to see this image in his media library.

i have found something here: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/13892
it is about changing something directly in database but does not work, not sure if im doing everything right though

anybody has experience with this or any ideas how should i proceed ?

Thanks

i have tried to modify database and pair those admin_permissions and admin_permissions_role_links but nothing seems to work.

Result should be that when i log as an author (user 1 or user 2) im able to see only those images that are uploaded by me (user 1 - user 1, user 2 - user 2)